# How does admob ads frequency (Frequency capping) work?

Tags: android, random, admob, ads, impressions

While setting admob unit for ads I was asked to check this :

-No cap on impressions

or

-Show no more than ____ impressions per user per ____ MINUTES

In my app I wrote code to generate random number (0,1,2) and then if number is 1 i request an ad, so there are 33 % chances that user will see ad (1 in 3).

My question is if my code for that is necessary if you can use that second option and how will that work (if i set no more that 5 impression per 1 minute will i realy request an ad only 5 times in minute or how ?, I don't understand, I have a game where ad is show when you fail in level, so what if you fail 15 times in 1 minute to reach next level with that setting of 5 impressions per minute, will it show ad first 5 times in row or every 3rd time ?????? How can I test it when impressions on real ads in my own app can get me banned?  )

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to write logic on your end to show ads after inteval. Admob takes care of that ( changes made on admob on cap will be reflected within 1 day in your app without making any code changes ).
2. In you game ads request will be send to admob but it will be displayed every 3rd time ( depending upon the capacity setup in admob console ).
3. Setup testads in your app using AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice() (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder#addTestDevice(java.lang.String)). don't use real ads while testing. your app will be banned

Comment: "Setup testads in your app using AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice()"
I used test ads before but you can't set them to appear certain number of times in minute

Comment: @KingProb testads will work exactly similar to your online ads. https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/targeting#test_ads

Comment: please share logs if you face issues setting up based on cap per minute

Comment: can i use real ads with added test device ?

Comment: not sure understood your question but you shoudn't use real ads on test devices.